# Appacelerator Titanium Studio error at build: failed to run dexer

Tags: android, titanium, titanium-android, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-studio

I've installed Appcelerator Studio. And I've chosen a Titanium classic build under:Get Started Quickly With Sample Apps.

I then run the application as an Android build (connected to my Android device via USB) and get the following errors:

```
[ERROR] :  Failed to run dexer:
[ERROR] :  
[ERROR] :  Error: Unable to access jarfile null
2016-01-26T01:48:05.090Z | TRACE  | titanium exited with exit code 1
2016-01-26T01:48:05.091Z | ERROR  | Error: ti run exited with error code 1
at ChildProcess.<anonymous>    (/Users/adilarif/.appcelerator/install/5.1.0/package/node_modules/appc-cli- titanium/plugins/run.js:92:66)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1074:12)
2016-01-26T01:48:05.091Z | TRACE  | Sending exit signal to titanium   process:  25607
[ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process   exit value was 1
```

**UPDATE 2**

Tried the following command -

```
appc ti config android.dx.maxMemory 512M
```

[ti config dx size 512M image capture in terminal Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMckw.png)

Moved dx.jar file to

```
/Users/adilarif1/Library/android-sdk-macosx/tools/lib
```

**UPDATE 3**

I implemented a setup check by cmd -

```
appc ti setup check.


──────────────────┤ Check Environment ├───────────────────

Node.js
  ✓  node               installed (v0.12.7)
  ✓  npm                installed (v2.11.3)

Titanium CLI
  ★  cli                new version v5.0.6 available (currently v5.0.5)

Titanium CLI Dependencies
  ✓  async              up-to-date (v1.4.2)
  ✓  colors             up-to-date (v1.1.2)
  ✓  fields             up-to-date (v0.1.24)
  ✓  humanize           up-to-date (v0.0.9)
  ✓  longjohn           up-to-date (v0.2.9)
  ✓  moment             up-to-date (v2.10.6)
  ✓  node-appc          up-to-date (v0.2.31)
  ✓  request            up-to-date (v2.62.0)
  ✓  semver             up-to-date (v5.0.3)
  ✓  sprintf            up-to-date (v0.1.5)
  ✓  temp               up-to-date (v0.8.3)
  ✓  winston            up-to-date (v1.0.2)
  ✕  wrench             missing

Titanium SDK
  ✓  latest sdk         installed (v5.1.2.GA)
  ✓  selected sdk       up-to-date (v5.1.2.GA)

Mac OS X Environment
  ✓  CLI Tools          installed

iOS Environment
  !  Xcode              no Xcode installations found
  !  iOS SDK            no Xcode installations found
  !  WWDR cert          not found
  !  developer cert     not found
  !  distribution cert  not found
  !  dev provisioning   not found
  !  dist provisioning  not found

Android Environment
   ✓  sdk                installed (/Users/adilarif/Library/android-sdk-macosx)
   !  tools              untested version 24.4.1; may or may not work
   ✓  platform tools     installed (v23.1)
   ✕  build tools        unsupported version 2.1.1.2
   ✓  adb                installed /Users/adilarif/Library/android-sdk-   macosx/platform-tools/adb
   ✓  android            installed /Users/adilarif/Library/android-sdk-macosx/tools/android
   ✓  emulator           installed /Users/adilarif/Library/android-sdk-macosx/tools/emulator
   ✓  mksdcard           installed /Users/adilarif/Library/android-sdk-macosx/tools/mksdcard
   ✓  zipalign           installed /Users/adilarif/Library/android-sdk-macosx/tools/zipalign
   ✓  aapt               installed /Users/adilarif/Library/android-sdk-macosx/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt
   ✓  aidl               installed /Users/adilarif/Library/android-sdk-  macosx/build-tools/23.0.1/aidl
   ✓  targets            installed (4 found)
   ✓  avds               installed (1 found)
   !  ndk                Android NDK not found

Java Development Kit
   ✓  jdk                installed (v1.8.0)
   ✓  java               installed   /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_71.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
   ✓  javac              installed /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_71.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/javac
   ✓  keytool            installed /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_71.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/keytool
   ✓  jarsigner          installed /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_71.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/jarsigner

Intel® Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager (HAXM)
   ✓  compatible         
   ✓  installed          

Network
   ✓  online             
   -  no proxy server configured 
   ✕  https://www.google.com (HTTP status: 404) is unreachable 
   ✓  Java-based connection test 

Directory Permissions
   ✓  home directory     
   ✓  titanium config directory 
   ✓  titanium sdk install directory 
   ✓  workspace directory 
   ✓  temp directory
```

Comment: Please don't just post an image; describe the problem you have **in detail** and explain any attempts you have made to solve it.

Comment: Can anyone help ASAP?

Answer (score 0):

Lowering the memory for java  has solved the problem to other people with issues with the dex process:

`ti config android.dx.maxMemory 512M`

However, there is this `Error: Unable to access jarfile null` that might be related to [this issue](https://archive.appcelerator.com/question/134780/how-can-i-resolve-this-error/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'll give both options ago.

Comment: Hi Joscandreu. I've tried both suggestions and I still get the same errors.

Comment: I have also installed build tools for 22.0.1 of the Android SDK: https://archive.appcelerator.com/question/182662

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm out of possible solutions for your problem.